# Content provider for ionic application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, android-contentprovider

A content provider component in Android supplies data from one application to others on request. I am looking for equivalent feature or plugin for Ionic mobile application. I want other applications(both native and ionic) to access data of one ionic application. Please let me know if it is possible using any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found a github project that maybe can help you:

https://github.com/r-cohen/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin

To install this plugin enter the following commands:

Through Cordova Repo (stable):

```
cordova plugin add com.phearme.cordovaplugin.contentproviderplugin
```

Through Github Repo (latest):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phearme/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin
```

Here is an example of the usage:

```
window.plugins.contentproviderplugin.query({
        contentUri: "content://sms/inbox",
        projection: ["address", "date", "body"],
        selection: null,
        selectionArgs: null,
        sortOrder: "date DESC"
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("error query");
    });
```

There is also a note about the permission you can find it in the link I provided you.

Comment: I have already checked it. It allows you to access existing content providers but it won't let you create your own content provider and register it. It is expected to work for both android and iOS.